# DB2 C UDF parameters in array

Tags: c, db2, user-defined-functions, db2-luw

I'm using DB2 10.5 Linux and I Need to create a C UDF that can get more than 150 arguments ( plus the null indicators ).

It is possible to pass the whole row like  `SELECT MYSCHEMA.MYUDF(*) FROM TABLE` or is there a way to pass the arguments in an array like PARAMETER STYLE MAIN in procedures ?

I haven't found any example or documentation for this.

Comment: I'm completely captivated by this question: what might a UDF do with 150 parameters?

Comment: Create a buffer with raw data, needed for other applications

Comment: For currently shipping Db2-LUW versions , the maximum number of parameters in a User-Defined-Function is 90, according to the documentation.  ( https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001029.html )  .  Choose a different design.

Comment: Any reason you can't use a temporary table with "more than 150" rows to pass your arguments?

Comment: is not possible to use temporary tables, the system is already set up.

Comment: You may wrap all your parameters to a single `CLOB` one with: `SELECT XMLSERIALIZE(XMLROW(C1, C2) AS CLOB(1K)) FROM (VALUES (1, CAST(NULL AS INT))) T(C1, C2)`, and parse them in your routine as XML. See the [XMLROW scalar function](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0050587.html) description.

Comment: "the system is already set up" and yet you are planning to create an external UDF... Don't see how declaring a temp table could be more complicated.

Comment: A temp table wold solve anything if I need to call a complex arithmetic aggregate operation with "150 columns".  and this needs to be call billions of times in a single run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is not possible to have more than 90 parameters, however I was able to solve the problem using BLOB as input.

then create the blob on query with (columns are INT)

```
HEXTORAW(HEX(COLUM_NAME_1))||HEXTORAW(HEX(COLUM_NAME_2))
```

then in C using a packed structure.

works much faster and reduces the code lines in on the C udf.